# When is a nef line bundle big

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, line-bundles

Suppose $M^n$ is a smooth projective variety. A line bundle $L$ on $M$ is nef (numerically effective) if on any complete curve $C$ in $M$, $L$ has positive degree, i.e.
$$
L\cdot C=\int_{C}R_h\geq 0.
$$
where $R_h$ is the curvature form of any Hermitian metric $h$ on $L$.

A line bundle $L$ on $M$ is big if there exist constants $m_0$ and $c>0$ such that
$$
h^0(M,L^m)=\operatorname{dim} H^0(M,L^m)\geq cm^n.
$$
for all $m\geq m_0$.

I read a result which states that by Riemann-Roch theorem that a nef line bundle is big if and only if $\int_Mc_1(L)^n>0$. The reference given by the author is Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry*, which is written in the language of algebraic geometry. However, I'm not familiar with it. Can anyone explain the result and Riemann-Roch theorem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Citing books by GTM number but not by title is a bit obfuscatory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right reference for this material is probably Lazarsfeld's book *Positivity in Algebraic Geometry*, Volume $1$, and this is a combination of results. (I'd argue it does not follow immediately from Riemann-Roch.) This book is also written in the language of algebraic geometry, but it at least contains this result. See the end of section 1.4 for example.

For a vector bundle $E$ we can define the Euler characteristic $\chi(M, E) = \sum_i (-1)^i h^i(M, E)$. Riemann-Roch theorems seek to compute this using the intersection theory of $M$ and $E$. For our purpose, we only need the following version of the asymptotic Riemann-Roch theorem.

> **Theorem**: Let $L$ be a line bundle on (a smooth projective variety) $M$. Then, $$\chi(M, L^m) = Cm^n + O(m^{n - 1})$$ is a polynomial in $m$ of degree $\leq n$, where $C = \int_M c_1(L)^n$.

When $L$ is nef we also have the following fact which controls the asymptotic growth of the higher cohomology.

> **Theorem**: Let $L$ be a nef line bundle on $M$. Then $$h^i(M, L^m) = O(m^{n - i})$$ for $m$ sufficiently large and $i \geq 0$.

Together, these theorems imply that for a nef line bundle, we can describe the asymptotic growth $h^0(M, L^m)$ to be $$h^0(M, L^m) = \left (\int_M c_1(L)^n\right)m^n + O(m^{n - 1})$$ for $m$ sufficiently large. In particular, $L$ is big if and only if this first coefficient is positive.

Both these theorems are nontrivial and require a significant amount of algebraic geometry to prove. The proof of the second fact is given under theorem 1.4.40 in Lazarsfeld's book, and uses vanishing theorems. The asymptotic Riemann-Roch theorem is stated in Lazarsfeld's book but a proof can only be found elsewhere. (Olivier Debarre's *Higher Dimensional Algebraic Geometry*, for example.) Both these books assume and use a lot of the language algebraic geometry, though.